Longtable endlast head
As inspired by this question,
Caption at foot of long tables ('longtable' package)
I would like to modify mylongtable with caption on top (it was caption on foot in the question), but there is no endlasthead as well, how can I do that?

you can't do that as longtable doesn't know when it starts the last page that that is the last page.

Thanks for clarification! I thought there is a way to modify the code in the example as it can do the same for caption on below ;)
